# UDK and Protocol Buffers

Tags: c++, networking, udk, unreal

Actually two questions:

1. Can I use TCP sockets in UDK to implement my own networking protocol? (I guess TCPLink is an answer)
2. Is there any way I can user Protocol Buffers inside UDK? Or anything like that? (i.e. thrift, bson)